# Shopware How to get SalesChannelContext in OrderWrittenEvent in order to send Mail?

Tags: shopware, shopware6, shopware6-api

I have a situation where I want to send emails from the order written event whenever an order has been updated according to some set of conditions that I will implement (for example an API response error) But unfortunately I have been unable to do so.

I first created a controller and an email service which uses the abstract email service of shopware And from my controller I'm able to send an email But when I tried to do the same in the event,I quickly realized that it wasn't doing exactly what I was expecting it to do. After some research on it, I saw that the event actually don't have access to the sales channel context so I tried multiple different ways to solve this issue but I'm still stuck. Can somebody please guide me on how I can implement that? thank you very much.

an example of what I tried is to call the store API in order to get the context of the saleschannel to use it in my sendMail function But it was giving errors such as:
request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception TypeError: "Argument 5 passed to Swag\BasicExample\Service\EmailService::sendMail() must be an instance of Shopware\Core\System\SalesChannel\SalesChannelContext, instance of stdClass given.

I obviously understand that I have to give it a Shopware\Core\System\SalesChannel\SalesChannelContext not an STD class but how can I do that? since it doesn't really see the channel context.

Answer (score 0):

If you do have an instance of `OrderEntity` you can rebuild the `SalesChannelContext` from the existing order using the `OrderConverter` service.

```xml
<service id="Foo\MyPlugin\Subscriber\MySubscriber">
    <argument type="service" id="Shopware\Core\Checkout\Cart\Order\OrderConverter"/>
    <argument type="service" id="order.repository"/>
    <tag name="kernel.event_subscriber"/>
</service>
```

```php
class MySubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private OrderConverter $orderConverter;
    
    private EntityRepository $repository;

    public function __construct(
        OrderConverter $orderConverter,
        EntityRepository $repository
    ) {
        $this->orderConverter = $orderConverter;
        $this->repository = $repository;
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            OrderEvents::ORDER_WRITTEN_EVENT => 'onOrderWritten',
        ];
    }

    public function onOrderWritten(EntityWrittenEvent $event): void
    {
        foreach ($event->getWriteResults() as $writeResult) {
            $orderId = $writeResult->getPrimaryKey();

            $criteria = new Criteria([$orderId]);
            $criteria->addAssociation('transactions');
            $criteria->addAssociation('orderCustomer');
            $order = $this->repository
                ->search($criteria, $event->getContext())->first();
            
            if (!$order instanceof OrderEntity) {
                continue;
            }
            
            $salesChannelContext = $this->orderConverter
                ->assembleSalesChannelContext($order, $event->getContext());
            
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am having this error:            request.ERROR: Uncaught PHP Exception Shopware\Core\Checkout\Cart\Exception\MissingOrderRelationException: "The required relation "transactions" is missing ." at [PATH]/vendor/shopware/core/Checkout/Cart/Order/OrderConverter.php line 258 {"exception":"[object] (Shopware\\Core\\Checkout\\Cart\\Exception\\MissingOrderRelationException(code: 0): The required relation \"transactions\" is missing . at /home/schcmjkg/staging/vendor/shopware/core/Checkout/Cart/Order/OrderConverter.php:258)"}

Comment: Yep, sorry, forgot. There is a required set of associations you need to provide when assembling the context. I updated my answer.